# C# parse Collection of items returned from PowerShell Command

Tags: c#, list, parsing, powershell

I'm trying to use some of the PowerShell Azure commands in C#. In case when property of returned object is a single element (string/int/..) it works just great, something like:

```
    foreach (PSObject xx in results)
    {
        PSMemberInfo ObjectId = xx.Properties["ObjectId"];
        PSMemberInfo DisplayName = xx.Properties["DisplayName"];
    }
```

As a result I can access their values by ObjectId.Value or DisplayName.Value. It works great.

However I can't get values if data of returned PowerShell property is not a single element, but a collection of something. For example if I get PS object like:

```
ExtensionData         : System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject
AccountEnabled        : True
Addresses             : {}
AppPrincipalId        : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
DisplayName           : access_00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
ObjectId              : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
ServicePrincipalNames : {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, access_00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
TrustedForDelegation  : False
```

Note that ServicePrincipalNames and Addresses are lists. In this case `xx.Properties["ServicePrincipalNames"]` contains a list, if I simply WriteLine it (`Console.WriteLine(xx.Properties["ServicePrincipalNames"].Value);`) I'll see: "`System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]`" so this looks like a collection, though I can't iterate over it. If I try:

```
foreach(var g in ...)
```

Compiler brings an error that `xx.Properties["ServicePrincipalNames"].Value` is an object and does not have any enumerators.

Google doesn't help much. Anyone experienced before?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicit cast it into an enumerator:

```
var principalNames = (List<string>)xx.Properties["ServicePrincipalNames"].Value;
foreach(var principalName in principalNames) {...}
```